# Graphically select a subset of Shapely objects in a Jupyter/iPython notebook

Tags: python, shapely, ipython, jupyter-notebook

This question is being [cross-posted from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360972/graphically-select-shapely-objects-in-a-jupyter-ipython-notebook).

The interoperability between Shapely and Jupyter/iPython is *nice*. I can do cool stuff like create a bunch of geometric shapes and view them in the notebook:

```
some_nodes = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
some_boxes = []
some_boxes.append([some_nodes[0], some_nodes[3], some_nodes[4], some_nodes[1]])
some_boxes.append([some_nodes[1], some_nodes[4], some_nodes[5], some_nodes[2]])

from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon
MultiPolygon([Polygon(box) for box in some_boxes])
```

...and Jupyter will show me this:

[image: Jupyter_Shapely_output]

Now THAT is cool! It has been especially useful to me for quickly viewing and editing, for example, polygons that make up 2D finite element meshes.

Sadly, the images produced are just static SVG graphics; there's no interaction built in. It would be helpful to be able to select a subset of those objects in the image using this same graphical interface in iPython.

More specifically, I'd like to be able to create a list and add some of the displayed polygons to it by, for example, clicking/selecting them, or dragging a lasso/box around them, and also perhaps remove them when clicking a second time.

I've looked into trying to do this with matplotlib or javascript and although I've had some initial success it's probably the kind of project that is out of my depth at my current level of knowledge/skill.

Since Jupyter is a somewhat sprawling tool with lots of features that I am probably not aware of, I am wondering if there are already existing solutions out there for interaction of this sort in the context of a Jupyter notebook?

UPDATE: It looks like I'm going to have to create something myself. Happily, [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/o7Tb7YhJZR0?list=PLAshlHpA2IwdlMxzOJqwD1GEToQLAD7_vA) is going to make that a LOT easier.

Comment: This is going to be tough. Esri has built a series of widgets for Jupyter notebook called ArcGIS for Python API. You may look at that should you be also an ArcGIS user. Otherwise, you would need to hook into the data using most likely JS and built a tiny HTML application that would be able to listen and react on user clicks. I'd recommend building a separate a web application for this instead of trying to use the Jupyter. Consider geojson - there are some decent online editors. http://geojson.io/

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Thanks for the feedback- I had a feeling this is a pretty complex task. I'm not an ArcGIS user. I'll look into geojson! I know shapely has import/export interop capability with geojson, though I've never used it.

Comment: Look at [Interactive maps with Bokeh](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2016/Lesson5-interactive-map-bokeh.html) for example (GeoPandas uses Shapely)

Comment: @gene Great - helpful! That tool certainly looks like it could be shoehorned into doing what I'm after. I guess it's time to give up hope that someone else has already done all of the work for me.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Are you aware of any reason I should avoid using [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in favor of developing my own web application, per your recommendation above?

Comment: When building an own app, you will have control over everything. When developing an `ipywidget`, you are restricted by what you can do there. I am almost certain you will spend a lot of time making it possible to interact with features drawn in a widget particularly if you are going to edit them. If you would like to have a hobby project with Python, go for it of course :) or let's say like this - if you would like to only *select* features, you might think `ipywidget`. But if you are going to edit features (get hands at vertices, handling XY event click in the html panel - think JS web app.

Comment: You might also look at other packages that will let you interact with your data using selectors, I believe `bokeh` can do that.